# Debugging COM reference counters

Tags: c++, debugging, com, reference

In a project, I'm talking to an object in a .EXE server (the object performs expensive queries for me which should be cached), and I seem to have gotten my reference counts wrong, which makes the server process free an object it still holds a reference to, making the host process fail in curious and interesting ways that involve losing data and sending a bug report to the vendor.

Is there a way I can ask COM to raise some condition that is detectable in a debugger if a proxy object whose refcount has dropped to zero is used in some way?

Comment: If your client process does extra `IUnknown::Release` for some unexpected reason, I would not expect it to be forwarded to real application. Instead it would destroy a proxy, while server process stub will still manage reference count correctly on the real object.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd expect -- however I'm able to make the server application pop up a window that some object's reference count just went negative.

Comment: More likely, it is a buggy server which does not expect the way you work with it. For example, it might be having internal COM objects which affect top level reference count, such as background worker activity which temporarily references main object while in progress.

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely that this is possible using raw interfaces - the reference count is maintained by the COM server and how it's impelmented is up to the server - the implementation is inside the server code, so unless you have the source and can debug the server, you have no way of getting to it.

However, it is likely your problem is cause by manually calling AddRef and Release. If that is the case, you can use a RAII/smart pointer solution. ATL provides one, but if for whatever reason you can't use that, it's easy enough to create your own. You can then not only create or use provided debugging facilities to keep track of reference counting, you will be much less likely to get it wrong in the first place.

Comment: The server is out-of-process, so I am guaranteed that the object living in my address space is a proxy. Hence my hope that I could use this fact for debugging.

Comment: I suppose if you're desperate, you could provide your own proxy dll that maintains a separate reference count and substitute the one in your registry for it, but it sure seems a lot of work.